# Do i need to install a driver to fix unstable wireless connection?

Tags: wireless

Basic question but i want to ask

Should i install some driver related to my wireless card?

i did not install any so far.

I do not know my wireless card model.

I am using ubuntu 11.

Comment: You should be able to find your card info with the lspci command (from a command line). Without knowing what card you have, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same  problem. I tried many solutions but never worked. In my search I found out various reasons for the problem

1. You need to disable **ipv6** in your browser.
2. Update the **kernel**.
3. Switch your router to **G mode** from **N mode**(or the vice-versa).

But after failing in all these attempts and a few more other. I formatted with 10.10 and configured the desktop(which was the main reason I upgraded to 11.10)

P.S: I would advise you to downgrade to 10.10 and give ubuntu sometime to improve on these issues. I'm sure they will.

Comment: thanks i do not want a format but it seems it is the only way to solve problem

Comment: There is way u can downgrade without complete disk formatting. You need to create a 30 gb partition install 10.10 alongside 11.10. Once you have successfully completed, format the partition where 11.10 resides.